# Angular Shallow unit test with subscribe

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine

I have inter component communication done via a service with RxJS subscriber.

Component that subscribes to this is configured as below:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(
    private myService: myService,
    private datePipe: DatePipe
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.mySubscription = this.myservice
      .getSubject()
      .subscribe(() => {
          //DO..SOMEYHING
          })
   }

 }
```

We are using shallow for testing, and myservice's subscription's next event is called by another component. How can we test above code block, as we are mocking service inside test.

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    shallow = new Shallow(MyComponent, MyModule)
      .mock(MyService, {

        getCount: () => of(25)
      })
  });
```

There is no way for us to send myservice.setSubject in test which would have triggered code in ngInit section.

Answer (score 0):

I would ask you to post the service code, but I´m gonna try to guess that the usage of the Subject is not the most recommended one (probably you have your own reasons).

I would have a service looking like this:

```
export class MyService {
    private subject = new Subject<number>();

    updateCount(n: number) {
        this.subject.next(n);
    }

    getCount(): Observable<number> {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

On the component side, in the `ngOnInit` method, I would not have retrieved the whole Subject, but the Subject as observable, and the subscription will look like this:

```
this.myservice
      .getCount()
      .subscribe(() => {
          //DO..SOMEYHING
          })
```

You mentioned that the *subscription next is called by another component*. Now you can use the **updateCount** method on the service, centralizing the logic in the service, and you can mock it easier.

Hope it helps!